# Postgresql & psycopg2: database does not exist

Tags: python, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, psycopg2

I am trying to establish a connection to a database like this:

`psycopg2.connect(database="movies", user="lfcj", host="127.0.0.1");`

my `pg_hba.conf` file has a line:

TYPE  __  DATABASE___USER__ADDRESS___METHOD
 
`local   all          lfcj                   peer`

I am trying to use peer identification, and my SO user name is also `lfcj`.

When I log in postgresql like this, grant all privileges to `lfcj`, and run `\list` :

```
psql lfcj -h 127.0.0.1 -d movies 
Enter password:  'myPassword'

psql (9.4.1)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

movies=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE  movies TO lfcj WITH GRANT OPTION;
movies=#\list
```

I get this information:

```
                            List of databases
Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
--------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
movies  | lfcj     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/lfcj         +
        |          |          |             |             | lfcj=C*T*c*/lfcj+
```

So: the database `movies` exists, `lfcj` is the owner and has all priviliges. But when I run:

`psycopg2.connect(movies, lfcj);`

it throws an error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "movies" does not exist
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Two databases on different ports?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try connecting to the "postgres" database:

```
psql -d postgres
```

and then execute the following command:

```
show data_directory;
```

On 9.3.1.0-alpha1 that should return

```
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Postgres93/var
```

Then check which databases exist on the server using the shorthand `\l`

If all that works, it seems that Postgresapp called initdb successfully, but createdb failed. You can do that manually, just execute `createdb USERNAME` from the terminal (not inside psql)

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string should look like this:

```
psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres password=secret")
```

The connect method will give you a connection to the database so you will probably need to store it in a variable. Typically like this:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres password=secret")
```

You can also use a set of keywords like this:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="test", user="postgres", password="secret")
```

Comment: @Silver, I am using a script to run those commands, so I did not copy the `connect` command right, but the syntax is like you say, and it still does not work.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem here.

I had two versions of postgres installed. One in port 5432 and the other in port 5433, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmCZh.png)

When I tried to connect with:

```
conn = pg2.connect(dbname='my_db_name', user='my_user', host='localhost', port=5433, password='my_pass')
```

It worked and made the connection with all the databases within postgres version 9.5. When I switched to port 5432 I made the connection to the databases inside postgres version 11.